# hiding products for guest user M2

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, search, plugin

I have one question about showing products. I dont want to show products for guest user. Even when they search for those products they will not get that. Only logged in user will get those.

Can anyone give me some tips how we can implement this?

Comment: you can't show product for guest user right? in all category.

Comment: I have specific product which I dont want to not even in category, added one attribute in admin if that is active only then product will show for logged in user

Comment: show thoes product show to admin product level attribute is active for login custome ?

Comment: I want to hide them in search, Just not sure which event I should use for this

Answer (score 4):

You may use a plugin after `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getVisibility()` and set the return value to `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE` if you have a guest user (i.e. the customer is not logged in) and your product attribute is set.
Your custom attribute needs to be available in product lists otherwise loading a specific product collection could miss it.

Answer (score 1):

If customer is not logged-in you can restrict customer from category and product page.

Check the following module

```
vendor/magento/module-website-restriction/Observer/RestrictWebsite.php
```

You can add custom controller path in "webrestrictions.xml" if you override this file in your module

```
vendor/magento/module-website-restriction/etc/webrestrictions.xml
```

Alternate solution you can use before Plugin for below class for execute method

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Product/View.php
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Category/View.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use events in this approach

event name = catalog_block_product_list_collection

in the execute function you can remove all products  like this

add events.xml to your module

**etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_block_product_list_collection">
        <observer instance="{vendor}\{module}\Observer\Frontend\Catalog\BlockProductListCollection" name="{vendor}_{module}_observer_frontend_catalog_blockproductlistcollection_catalog_block_product_list_collection"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

and this code to your observer file

**/app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/Observer/Catalog/BlockProductListCollection.php**

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Observer\Catalog;

class BlockProductListCollection implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {

        // if(customer is not loggedin) 
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $k => $product){
                 $collection->removeItemByKey($k);
        }

    }
}
```